# Overloading Addition (+) operator for own classes/objects

Tags: matlab, oop, operator-overloading

I created a class `xyz` which results in a matrix comprising only integers. If I try to add two instances of that class, I do receive the error message:

> "Undefined operator '+' for input arguments of type 'xyz'."

What am I supposed to do to make the in-built `+` operator compatible with instances of my class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the [`plus` method to override the behavior of `+`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/implementing-operators-for-your-class.html#responsive_offcanvas)

```
classdef MyObject

    properties
        value
    end

    methods
        function this = MyObject(v)
            this.value = v;
        end

        function result = plus(this, that)
            % Create a new object by adding the value property of the two objects
            result = MyObject(this.value + that.value);
        end
    end
end
```

Then use it like:

```
one = MyObject(1)
%  MyObject with properties:
%
%   value: 1


two = MyObject(2)
%  MyObject with properties:
%
%   value: 2

three = one + two
%  MyObject with properties:
%
%   value: 3
```

For other common operators, there is an extensive list [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/implementing-operators-for-your-class.html#br02znk-6)